# 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: flashdevelop, haxe, nme

I tried to run a project using custom build in FlashDevelop:

```
$(CompilerPath)\haxe.exe $(ProjectDir)\compile-js.hxml
```

, but I get this error:

'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

here is the compile-js.hxml file, is there any idea how to solve this?

compile-js.hxml

```
#sources
-main Cocktail
-cp ../../src/
-cp src

#binary
-js bin/js/Main.js
--macro Cocktail.create('src/index.html','Main')

#copy assets directory
-cmd cp -R assets bin\js\
```

Comment: It worked for me this wayl i changed frm this--> `"cp ./data/orig-db.json ./data/db.json && json-server --watch ./data/db.json"`
to this-->`"copy .\\data\\orig-db.json .\\data\\db.json && json-server --watch .\\data\\db.json"`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I'm guessing if you're on Flashdevelop, you're running Windows, and if you're running windows, there's no such thing as the 'cp' command.  When haxe has finished building your Javascript, it gets to the `-cmd` line and attempts to run `cp -R assets bin\js\`, which will fail because windows doesn't have `cp`, it has `copy`.

For Windows, try changing the last two lines to something like:

```
#copy assets directory
-cmd copy \y assets bin\js\
```

** Disclaimer: I'm not in Windows at the moment, so am not certain about the exact syntax of the [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy) command.  But you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, I've got your point, I have downloaded this https://github.com/bmatzelle/gow to run linux commands, and I have added an environment path to its bit folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Gow\bin

which contains linux commands in form of exe files

But I still have the error:

'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I hope I can fix this, how can I benefit from gow above?

Comment: Oh the joys of Windows and its different commands 

Answer (score 24):

[Stolen from Here :)](https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-basics/issues/2)

if you're running on windows you have to replace "cp" with "copy"

Answer (score 3):

in my case I was using windows default command prompt to install a node package. I used [GitBash Shell](https://gitforwindows.org/) and **Yahoo.....**.

Answer (score 3):

Change cp to copy

For example: I was trying this `cp -a themes/hugo-curious/exampleSite/* .`

Change to `copy themes\\hugo-curious\\exampleSite\\* .`

Answer (score 2):

if you are using windows, try the same in git bash, worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if you have cygwin installed in the Windows Box, or using UNIX Shell then

```
Issue bash#which cp
```

This will tell you whether cp is in your classpath or NOT.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on **Windows cmd**, then follow this. **It worked for me !**

webpack -d && copy src\index.html dist\index.html && webpack-dev-server --content-base src --inline --hot

Found here: https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/reactjs-basics/issues/2#issuecomment-274776347 (thanks to [medigvijay](https://github.com/medigvijay))

Answer (score 0):

copy node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.mix.js .\

Comment: Care to add an explanation to this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this error in Python
Try:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(source,target)
```

Answer (score 0):

git bash worked for me. try executing the command in git bash.

i ran the command in normal command window and execution failed, then i tried with git bash and executed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I face similar issues while using windows
the changes I make
change "cp" to "copy"

and all the "/" in the direcotry I change it to the    "\"

in your case

your command =>  -cmd cp -R assets bin\js
update command for windows => -cmd copy -R assets bin\js

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Using the `xcopy` command works.

Comment: Please do provide an example of how the xcopy command works; sample code